# Octave operator \ error

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, division

I'm working in GNU Octave and i need to solve the following equation: `A*x=b` (A, x, b are matrix).

```
A = [1 1; 2 1];
b = [1, 2];
```

So i'm doing `x = A \ b` according to my guidelines. But I get an error:

```
operator \: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x2, op2 is 1x2)
```

I understand what it means, but don't know how to fix this. I've already tried `inv(A) * b`.

---

By the way it works perfectly in matlab. Here is my script:

```
A = input('Enter A');
b = input('Enter b');
x = A \ b;
display(x);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the dimension of `b` it should be columns rather than a row.

```
x = A\b.';
% or for clarity
x = A\transpose(b);
```

---

**Edit:**

If you use `inv` again you need to use the correct dimensions:

```
x = inv(A)*b.';
% or for clarity
x = inv(A)*transpose(b);
```

Comment: It works, but according to math x=A^(-1)*b. As i know operator \ is equivalent to this. So what's the matter?

Comment: That is true and you still need `inv(A)*b.'` to make the dimensions work out.

Comment: Can we verify that there is a MATLAB incompatibility here? That would warrant a bug report at bugs.octave.org

Comment: @NickJ That would be be helpful indeed. Unfortunately I do not have Octave, so I can not test it myself. (It work on Matlab, as long as you have the dimensions right)

Comment: I should have access to both later to test.  But I'm sort of surprised the script works. Should it?   I would expect MATLAB to have the same conformant operator restrictions.

Comment: From the MATLAB documentation `x = A\B solves the system of linear equations A*x = B. The matrices A and B must have the same number of rows.` The non-conformant arguments do not work on R2010b (only version I have).

Comment: correct. @mpaskov should correct the question. the code you state 'works perfectly in matlab' does not.  In 2016b you get "Error using _\\_   Matrix dimensions must agree"  just like in Octave.